# module error in drush

Tags: drush

My task is to update all modules of  a site and commit. Everything goes well except when I ran the command `drush pm-update projects drupal-6.28`

> PHP Fatal error:  Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /Users/scottnassery/c2d-deals2/sites/all/modules/contrib/uc_post_affiliate_pro/uc_post_affiliate_pro.module on line 926
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
>   Error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in
>   /Users/scottnassery/c2d-deals2/sites/all/modules/contrib/uc_post_affiliate_pro/uc_post_affiliate_pro.module,
>   line 926
>
> Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /Users/scottnassery/c2d-deals2/sites/all/modules/contrib/uc_post_affiliate_pro/uc_post_affiliate_pro.module on line 926
>   Scotts-MacBook-Pro-2:c2d-deals2 scottnassery$ drush up uc_post_affiliate_pro --security-only --no-core
>   PHP Fatal error:  Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /Users/scottnassery/c2d-deals2/sites/all/modules/contrib/uc_post_affiliate_pro/uc_post_affiliate_pro.module on line 926
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
>   Error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in
>   /Users/scottnassery/c2d-deals2/sites/all/modules/contrib/uc_post_affiliate_pro/uc_post_affiliate_pro.module,

My question is how can I fix that error and how can I restore the module to a old version should I redownload it  and replace it?

Answer (score 2):

Recently, Drush changed the default setting for recoverable errors to abort rather than continue when they are discovered. If this is causing problems, e.g. in an old module, then you can turn it off.

Create a file called `drushrc.php`, and place it in `$HOME/.drush`. Add the following contents:

```
<?php
$options['halt-on-error'] = FALSE;
```

You should then be able to continue without needing to fix the error in the non-compliant module.

Comment: I know Greg knows this, but for anyone else... This change was introduced in the pull request https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/1465 and makes drush handle recoverable errors more the way that Drupal does.

Comment: I added a proposal to relax this behavior for Drupal 6: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/2011

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in [Post Affiliate Pro](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_post_affiliate_pro) module, which is trying to pass a variable by reference to a function on call time. You can simply fix this bug by updating `uc_post_affiliate_pro.module` file on the line 926:

```
uc_post_affiliate_pro_register_affiliate($edit, &$account);
```

into

```
uc_post_affiliate_pro_register_affiliate($edit, $account);
```